# looping through an array of objects and getting the average

Tags: javascript

I am looking to to loop through an array of objects in my prototype function. After I loop I want to get the average of the gpa array and then console log the name, address, gpa and average gpa. I am able to do all but the average. I want this to all run together within the testing function. Thanks for all the help.

```
var students = [{
    name: "Walker",
    address: {
        street: "123 South Drive",
        city: 'Sarasota',
        state: 'FL'
    },
    gpa: [3.0, 3.4, 3.8]
}, {
    name: "Christian",
    address: {
        street: "5601 Pebble Beach Ln",
        city: 'Sacromento',
        state: 'CA'
    },
    gpa: [2.5, 3.6, 3.8]
}];

var stud = Students(students);



stud.testing();
```

constuctor.js:

```
var Students = function (students) {
    return new Students.prototype.init(students);
}

Students.prototype = {
    init: function (students) {
        this.students = students;
    },
    testing: function () {


        for (i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
            i = i % this.students.length;


            for (j = 0; j < this.students.length; j++) {



                this.gpa1 = this.students[j].gpa;
                this.len = this.students[j].gpa.length;

                //console.log(this.gpa1);

                this.average = this.gpa1[0] + this.gpa1[1] + this.gpa1[2];
                this.res = this.average / this.len;
                console.log(this.res);
            }




            console.log("Name: " + this.students[i].name);
            console.log("Address: " + this.students[i].address.street + ' ' + this.students[i].address.city + ' ' + this.students[i].address.state);
            console.log("GPA: " + this.students[i].gpa);
            console.log("Average: " + this.gpa1);


        }
    },
    addData: function (student3) {
        this.students.push(student3);
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have this line `i = i % this.students.length;`?

Comment: And why do you have a nested loop over the students array inside a loop over the students array?

Comment: I did this so I could console log the first object, then the second object without having more then one set of console logs. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I am just learning so i know my code is bad. I am just looking to improve.

Comment: Well you should decide whether the grade point array is called "gpa" or "gpa1".  It can't be both :)

Comment: @user3072159: Your requirements really aren't very clear. Perhaps you could add what you *expect* as output for your given input?

Comment: You've also forgetten the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have a starting-point to get the average, however, it looks like you're leaving it as the "total" instead:

```
this.average = this.gpa1[0] + this.gpa1[1] + this.gpa1[2];
```

Now, assuming that there will only ever be three grades, we could make just a small change:

```
this.average = (this.gpa1[0] + this.gpa1[1] + this.gpa1[2]) / 3.0;
```

If you want a more dynamic average, though it's probably not going to be the case, you could perform the calculations in a loop:

```
for (var avg = 0; avg < this.gpa1.length; avg++) {
    this.average += this.gpa1[avg];
}
this.average = this.average / this.gpa1.length;
```

Both of my solutions above are for calculating the average for each individual student; if you need to calculate a total average for *all* students, adjustments to the loop above should suffice but for a more precise example check out [@MattBurland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705638/1518087).

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy, loop over the students, then loop over their GPA score, add them up and divide by the total number of points:

```
testing: function () {
    var total = 0;
    var numPoints = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
        var thisStudentsTotal = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < this.students[i].gpa.length; j++) {
            total += this.students[i].gpa[j];
            thisStudentsTotal += this.students[i].gpa[j];
            numPoints++;
        }
        // This is the average for just this student
        this.students[i].myAvg = thisStudentsTotal / this.students[i].gpa.length;
    }
    // This is the average for every student
    var theAverage = total / numPoints;
}
```

Comment: Does the OP want the average of *all* of the students, or the average for each individual student?

Comment: @newfurniturey: beats me. But I've added both now.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to add the GPA average to the object before you loop over it. That way you can reuse it in other parts of the program without duplicating code.

Here I've used the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to add the average (to two decimal places) to each student object, simply because I think it's neater.

```
this.students.map(function (el) {
  el.avg = (el.gpa.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p + c;
  }) / el.gpa.length).toFixed(2);
  return el;
});
```

And now you just loop over the objects.

```
for (var i = 0, l = this.students.length; i < l; i++) {
  var student = this.students[i];
  console.log("Name: " + student.name);
  // etc
}
```

[I've added a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8W72M/4/) which includes your code, corrected slightly where I've seen an error. I've separated the `getAverageGpa` code into a new function.

Comment: Of course `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` both need to iterate through the collection so, essentially, you still have a nested loop.